# Animated or Reanimated in React Native. Which is the best

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I've been learning React Native and I'm trying to learn animations.

Upon searching a bit and discovering the possibilities I found out that you can use the **Animated** component from react-native but there is also the possibility to use the library **Reanimated** which is supposed to make easier the task of animating.

There are some differences between but I wanted to learn one and stick to it until I consider I have a good knowledge about it.

Which one do you consider it's the **best**?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how complex you want your project to be, and also what type of navigation library you are using.

In one of the projects that I'm working on we are using reanimated. But due to debugging difficulties and dependency collisions, we decided to remove it.

Also, they share a common understanding in animations. I don't say they are fully compatible but if you can learn Vanilla Animated library, you can easily use Reanimated too.